# Apache Camel: do Processors and Beans serve the same purpose?

Tags: apache-camel

It seems like both serve the same purpose. Is there any difference that makes one useful in certain situations and not the other ?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

In practice, they are very similar, but a Processor is more limited than a Bean.  I generally use a Processor for simple use cases that just interact with the Exchange.  Also, [inline processors](http://camel.apache.org/processor.html) are a great way to interact without having to create a separate class.

Beans provide more flexibility and also support a true POJO approach.  This allows you to more easily integrate with existing APIs (just need to convert the inputs/outputs to match, etc).

Beans also provide great features/flexibility with regards to Camel routing/EIP integration, including...

- rich set of [bindings](http://camel.apache.org/bean-binding.html) that allow you to quickly bind data from the Exchange to attributes of a bean method, etc.
- POJO [consuming](http://camel.apache.org/pojo-consuming.html)/[producing](http://camel.apache.org/pojo-producing.html) allow you to interact with endpoints in a reusable manner
- [used as expressions/predicates](http://camel.apache.org/bean-language.html) (for POJO EIP implementation...filters, etc)

Answer (score 13):

Boils down to a matter of preference, I'd say.  I generally opt for the POJO approach and so I started using beans to do my processing, but over time I've slowly moved to using Processors.

I was feeling pain in the following cases:

- Bean methods with more than one parameter
- Trying to get data out of the exchange params / the message headers

I know that Camel 2.8 takes out some of the pain of these cases by allowing [annotations in your bean](http://camel.apache.org/bean-binding.html) which guide Camel on how to call your bean's methods.  I didn't want to go this route -- felt wrong to put Camel annotations into a bean that shouldn't care that it's being called by Camel.

In the end we created an annotation-free, client-agnostic bean and a very thin Processor that pulls everything it needs from camel and passes it to that bean.

Just my 2 cents - the bean route really isn't a bad one - it'll do the job just as well (esp in 2.8)

**EDIT**

Many improvements have been made to camel's use of POJOs to process messages since this was written - this answer may no longer be applicable.