# Advantage of using beanref instead of processref in Apache camel

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel

While writing a camel route I am calling java class, we have two options like either we can use a processor or a spring bean. Is there any advantage of using a beanref instead of processref.

Answer (score 2):

I personally feel you what you can do with the processor can be done with a bean component too and vice versa. If the bean already exists, it can be easily integrated with camel instead of duplicating the code again in the processor or invoking the bean in a processor to perform the same task. I consider this as one differentiating factor.

Infact, this sounds a duplicate question. Take a look at [this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6061813/apache-camel-do-processors-and-beans-serve-the-same-purpose)